# $.fn.dataTable.Editor is not a constructor - RequireJS with DataTables

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, jquery-datatables-editor

Library versions:
jQuery                              : 2.1.1
DataTables                          : 1.10.1-dev
dataTablesTableTools                : 2.2.1
dataTables.dataTables.editor.min.js : 1.2.3

I'm trying to implement CRUD operation using datatableseditor using Backbone, RequireJS and Datatables.But I'm getting the error message:

```
$.fn.dataTable.Editor is not a constructor"
```

What could be the reason?

Here is my configuration:

```
require.config({
baseUrl: 'js',
paths: {
    jquery: 'vendor/jquery.min',
    datatables: 'vendor/jquery.dataTables.min',
    datatablesTableTools: 'vendor/dataTables.tableTools.min',
    datatablesEditor: 'vendor/dataTables.editor.min'
},
shim: {
    jquery : {
        exports : '$'
    },
    datatables: { 
        deps: [
            'jquery',                
        ] 
    },
    datatablesTableTools:   { deps: ['datatables'] },
    datatablesEditor:       { deps: ['datatables'] }        
}
});
```

Using it as follows:

```
require(["jquery", "datatables"], function () {

var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
    "ajax": "table.line.php"
} );

$('#myGrid').dataTable( {
    "aaData": [
        ['Trident', 'Internet Explorer 4.0', 'Win 95+', 4, 'X'],
        ['Trident', 'Internet Explorer 5.0', 'Win 95+', 5, 'C']
    ],
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sTitle": "Engine" },
        { "sTitle": "Browser" },
        { "sTitle": "Platform" },
        { "sTitle": "Version" },
        { "sTitle": "Grade" }
    ],
    "tableTools": {
        "sRowSelect": "os",
        "aButtons": [
            { "sExtends": "editor_create", "editor": editor },
            { "sExtends": "editor_edit",   "editor": editor },
            { "sExtends": "editor_remove", "editor": editor }
        ]
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have made a mistake in your table of dependencies. In your second code, it should be like this :

```
require(["jquery", "datatablesEditor"], function () {
[...]
```

instead of

```
require(["jquery", "datatables"], function () {
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've checked and it's more vicious. When you look the source code of the plugin datatables-fixedcolumns for example, its name is specified so you need to use it instead of your own alias/name.

The source code dataTables.fixedColumns.js :

```
[...]
// Define as an AMD module if possible
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
    define( 'datatables-fixedcolumns', ['jquery', 'datatables'], factory );
}
else if ( jQuery && !jQuery.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns ) {
    // Otherwise simply initialise as normal, stopping multiple evaluation
    factory( jQuery, jQuery.fn.dataTable );
}
[...]
```

So in your requirejs.config, you need to write this :

```
[...]
paths: {
    jquery: 'vendor/jquery.min',
    datatables: 'vendor/jquery.dataTables.min',
    datatables-fixedcolumns: 'vendor/dataTables.fixedColumns'
[...]
```

instead of

```
[...]
paths: {
    jquery: 'vendor/jquery.min',
    datatables: 'vendor/jquery.dataTables.min',
    datatablesFixedColumns: 'vendor/dataTables.fixedColumns'
[...]
```